# Node.js livereload solution (watch only loaded files, css refresh, script inject)

Tags: node.js, livereload

Is there an solution for live loading (refreshing of the page when code is change) for node.js that satisfies the following requirements:

1) Watches only files loaded by page (not all files in certain directories as for example grunt-watch does)
2) Refreshes css without full page reload.
3) Requires NO extension for browser (injects some script on the page)

Thanks.